# Compiled game of Minecraft Alpha 1.2.6 crashing when I hit f3 ingame (after a string modification)

Tags: crash, minecraft

[This is specifically for a really old verion of minecraft, specifically alpha 1.2.6.]
I honestly have no clue what is happening for this to happen, I make periodic build tests to check if they function, I've checked this build's code compared to a previous, no real differences besides the one string.

Here's the somewhat long console log for when the crash happens.
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:315)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:281)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:271)
at net.minecraft.src.GuiIngame.renderGameOverlay(GuiIngame.java:153)
at net.minecraft.src.EntityRenderer.func_4136_b(EntityRenderer.java:298)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:492)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.StringConcatException: Mismatched number of concat arguments: recipe wants 0 arguments, but signature provides 1
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.argumentMismatch(StringConcatFactory.java:428)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.parseRecipe(StringConcatFactory.java:414)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants(StringConcatFactory.java:341)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:102)
... 7 more

I've tried changing the string, placing the changes i made in both the .java and .class versions of the respective file (RetroMCP has 2 versions of src files that if they arent matching crash the game).

Comment: Just remembered I should probably give the portion of code that crashes.
  if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F3)) {
   var8.drawStringWithShadow("v1.2.7_10 Debug (" + this.mc.field_6292_I + ")", 2, 2, 16777215);